# UniqueId for autoform hook

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

This is probably are a really simple answer, however, I'm stumped. I have a lot of forms on my site. I would like to notify the user that an update form has been saved.

In this instance I'm creating a uniqueId, it's a Q&A form so there can be many question forms on one page.  I'm not sure how to use the uniqueId with `AutoForm.addHooks();`   everything I've tried to date creates global autoform hooks which is not ideal because it affects all the other forms on the site.

```
Template.answers.helpers({
  makeUniqueID: function () {
      return "update-each-" + this._id;
  },
});

var hooksObject = {
    onSuccess: function(formType, result) {
        var collectionId = this.docId;

        Meteor.call('sendEmail',
            collectionId
            );
    },
};

var answerForm = "update-each-" + this._id;
AutoForm.addHooks('answerForm', hooksObject);
```

**UPDATE**

Path: `answer.js`

```
var hooksObject = {
  onSuccess: function(formType, result) {
    var collectionId = this.docId;

    Meteor.call('sendEmail',
      collectionId
      );
  },
};

Template.answers.onCreated(function() {
  var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
        var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
        self.subscribe('answers', id);
    });
    this.formId = "update-each-" + this._id;
    console.log("oncreated: ", this.formId);

    AutoForm.addHooks(this.formId, hooksObject, true); 
});



Template.answers.helpers({
  answer: function() {
    return Answers.find({"userId": Meteor.userId()});
  },
  formId() {
   /**
    * expose the form id we set above to the template
    **/
      var test = Template.instance().formId;
      console.log("test: ", test);
      return Template.instance().formId;
   },
});
```

Path: `answer.html`

```
{{#each answer}}
  {{#autoForm id=formId type="update" collection="Answers" doc=this}}
  {{> afQuickField name='answer'}}
    <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
  {{/autoForm}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated based on new information from updated post and comment feedback.**
The key to this solution is calling `AutoForm.addHooks` inside your Template's onCreated event. Otherwise, you won't have access to the unique id:

*answers.html*

```
<template name="answers">
  {{#each answer}}
    {{> answerForm this }}
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

*answers.js*

```
Template.answers.onCreated(function() {
  this.autorun(() => {
    var id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    this.subscribe('answers', id);
  });      
});

Template.answers.helpers({
  answer: function() {
    return Answers.find({"userId": Meteor.userId()});
  }
});
```

*answer.html*

```
<template name="answerForm">
  {{#autoForm id=formId type="update" collection="Answers" doc=this}}
    {{> afQuickField name='answer'}}
    <button type="submit">Save changes</button>
  {{/autoForm}}
</template>
```

*answer.js*

```
Template.answerForm.onCreated(function onCreated() {
  /**
   * The data._id field is passed in to your template as data
   **/
  this.formId = "update-each-" + this.data._id;

  /**
   * Call addHooks with the third option, true, to replace any existing hooks for this form.
   * This is because addHooks will run every time an instance of this template is created.
   **/
  AutoForm.addHooks(this.formId, hooksObject, true);

});

Template.answerForm.helpers({
  formId() {
    /**
     * expose the form id we set above to the template
     **/
    return Template.instance().formId;
  }
});
```

Comment: Sorry. `this.formId = "update-each-" + this.data._id;` doesn't appear to be creating a unique Id for the update forms. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: This assumes that the `_id` field is passed in to your template as part of a data object, for example if the parent template had a reference `doc` to a Mongo document for that form, then you would call your answers template like so: 
`{{> answers doc}}`
`doc` just needs to be an object containing the _id field, here's the code I used when testing my example:
`Template.body.helpers({
  doc() {
   return { _id: 'asd12312' };
  }
});`
You will want to modify this to use the `this._id` field you were using in your original example. You didn't show where you were retrieving that field.

Comment: Hi Nathan, feeling a little sheepish. I'm still stumped. I've updated my code to try and implement what you suggested (see above), would you mind pointing out where I'm going wrong. Really feeling like a noob.

Comment: I updated my code based on your input. I think the confusion comes from me not knowing where you are getting the form id. Is that coming from the url via `FlowRouter.getParam('id')`?

Comment: The form id is the collection id. `FlowRouter.getParam('id')` is the id of the user. It isn't related to the form.

Comment: Ah, so the `_id` comes from the documents in `{{#each answer }}` .. I've updated the example again; my solution is based on you passing that data into the template. I've split your code into a parent and child template for this purpose.

Comment: Ahhh, Thanks heaps. It works now. So much still to learn. I appreciate all the help.